# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have found a lot of questions related to this, but not still able to over come mine. So I need help to solve it.

I have ViewPager with 2 Fragments and I tried to add ImageView to the second fragment but application crashed with this error. By the way when I just add TextView or Button without ImageView application, ViewPager works fine. How to solve my problem?

Thanks for any help!

**fragment_news.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/news_content"
          android:src="@drawable/news_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**NewsFragment.java**

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    }
}
```

**ERROR**:

```
02-23 15:14:32.877    1233-1233/www.smartavenue.com E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL 

    EXCEPTION: main
        Process: www.smartavenue.com, PID: 1233
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                at www.smartavenue.com.fragment.NewsFragment.onCreateView(NewsFragment.java:16)
                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onMeasure(CustomViewAbove.java:456)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use another image (a smaller) in your ImageView?

Comment: After you comment I tried it and it works with smaller imageview. So what max size of ImageView can be for your thinking?

Comment: I would say that it depends of memory allocated to your application (about 16MB by default I think but I'm not sure). But this error message isn't really explicit.

Comment: May be that you should load your image in a Bitmap and not directly in your xml file, you'll be able to configure the loading and ensure your image is correctly loaded. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: You know the interesting think is that I used more bigger ImageView in first Fragment but when I set ImageView which is more smaller that first one it didnt work. Really strange. What can you advice to me?

Comment: Thanks for information but in Bitmap it will be one size of ImageView to all diveces?

Comment: Yep, those kinds of stuff are usually tricky to understand. With a Bitmap you can resize, scale, your image based on your devices size and dpi I guess.
You can probably use this if you want to load from resources.
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

Answer (score 2):

It is good for me:

In Manifest:

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"
```

In .xml file, you must remove the below code:

```
android:src="@drawable..
android:background="@drawable...
```

Because the error is out of memory error